# Web3 Daemon Event listner

Tags: web3js, events, daemon

```
const DManage = new web3.eth.Contract(myABI, '0x9420D0904B2F696f8612239e5a507A86B5dA1b6a');
DManage.events.allEvents()
.on('data', (response) => {
    console.log(event);
})
.on('changed', (response) => {
    // remove event from local database
})
.on('error', console.error);
```

When I run this, the code executes without any errors. Why doesn't it go "daemon" mode? Shouldn't it listen to future events?

How can I get the web3 event listner (code above) run as a daemon? So that each time a event is emitted it will execute some code.